# HTML Iframe work with widevinecdm chrome component?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to iframe a website for some testing purposes. I have used a chrome extension that allows you to iframe any website. Problem is that with some websites I get the error about widevinecdm. Is it possible to let an iframe use widevinecdm from the chrome browser? Or is there a bypass or someway to get passes this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a doc for this: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes

Simply use the **allow="encrypted-media *;"** attribute on your iframe element, such as:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com" allow="encrypted-media *;"></iframe>
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.